# How do I create effective class hierarchy

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I want to create a basic `Item` class hierarchy.
Each `Item` will have a String name and an int itemID.
These variables will be set in each subclass of Item.
The Item class declares the two variables and each subclass of Item
(public class Hammer extends Item) will set the name and itemID.
For example, name = "hammer" and itemID = 01.
How would I do this efficiently and effectively?

Comment: What does, "efficiently and effectively" mean?  Please take some time to read [ask].  You will get better results that way.  Maybe start reading the java tutorials -https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: You Can put thé variables un thé superclass, all the fidèles ans méthodes shared by all items souls ne un the item class

Comment: This is not how object oriented programming is supposed to work. Subclasses should have additional fields and or behavior. If they just have different data (like in your example), they should be *instances* of the `Item` class, not subclasses.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele In the future I plan on having independent behavior for each item. The question I have asked has been answered, I was simply confused as to how to set variables of a superclass from within a subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base class will declare two final private fields (name and itemid).
The values for these will be set via the base class constructor.

Each of the derived classes will call the base class constructor with the appropriate name and itemid value.

for example:

```
public abstract class Blam
{
    private final int itemId;
    private final String name;

    protected(
        final int itemId,
        final String name)
    {
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.name = name;
    }
}


public class Derived
extends
    Blam
{
    public Derived()
    {
        super(123, "nameValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: Slight modification of your code brought me right where I needed to be. I plan on getting a book or two on Java as Object Orientation is the main 'selling point'. For now, I appreciate the quick answer.